# compass unable to generate sprites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, compass-sass

This is really weird, compass is not able to generate new sprites.

Nothing in the logs, all I can see is this stacktrace in the compiled css.

It started happening after I upgraded to ubuntu 11.10, but I don't think its something related to it.

I could find a similar post [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/compass-users/9P0iCm8WErE/124iQ7lXthAJ), but no solution was found for this either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Stacktrace:**

```
/*
SignalException: SIGTERM

Backtrace:
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/chunky_png-1.2.0/lib/chunky_png/canvas/operations.rb:102:in `replace!'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/chunky_png-1.2.0/lib/chunky_png/canvas/operations.rb:101:in `each'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/chunky_png-1.2.0/lib/chunky_png/canvas/operations.rb:101:in `replace!'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/compass-0.11.4/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines/chunky_png_engine.rb:22:in `construct_sprite'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/compass-0.11.4/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines/chunky_png_engine.rb:14:in `each'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/compass-0.11.4/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines/chunky_png_engine.rb:14:in `construct_sprite'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/compass-0.11.4/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/sprite_methods.rb:68:in `generate'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/compass-0.11.4/lib/compass/sass_extensions/functions/sprites.rb:98:in `sprite_url'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/compass-0.11.4/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/sprite_map.rb:51:in `send'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/compass-0.11.4/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/sprite_map.rb:51:in `method_missing'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/compass-0.11.4/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/sprite_map.rb:42:in `to_s'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/script/list.rb:37:in `to_s'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/script/list.rb:37:in `map'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/script/list.rb:37:in `to_s'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:216:in `visit_prop'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `send'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:18:in `visit'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `map'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:27:in `visit_children'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:39:in `with_environment'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:26:in `visit_children'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:230:in `visit_rule'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `send'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:18:in `visit'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:145:in `visit_import'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:145:in `map'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:145:in `visit_import'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `send'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:18:in `visit'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:145:in `visit_import'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:145:in `map'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:145:in `visit_import'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `send'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:18:in `visit'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:145:in `visit_import'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:145:in `map'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:145:in `visit_import'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `send'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:18:in `visit'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `map'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:27:in `visit_children'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:39:in `with_environment'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:26:in `visit_children'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:47:in `visit_root'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `send'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:18:in `visit'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:7:in `send'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:7:in `visit'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:291:in `_render'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:239:in `render'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/util.rb:297:in `silence_sass_warnings'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/lib/sass/../sass/engine.rb:239:in `render'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/rails/../lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:319:in `update_stylesheet'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/rails/../lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:181:in `update_stylesheets'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/rails/../lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:175:in `each'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/rails/../lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:175:in `update_stylesheets'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/rails/../lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:173:in `each'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/rails/../lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:173:in `update_stylesheets'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/rails/../lib/sass/plugin.rb:81:in `update_stylesheets'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/rails/../lib/sass/plugin.rb:54:in `check_for_updates'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/sass-3.1.4/rails/../lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:51:in `call'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.1.0/lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:18:in `call'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.1.0/lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:24:in `call'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:99:in `call'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in `call'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:34:in `run'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@project/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in `call'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:513:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:321:in `start_request_handler'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:275:in `send'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:270:in `handle_spawn_application'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:149:in `start'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:219:in `spawn_rails_application'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:214:in `spawn_rails_application'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `synchronize'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:213:in `spawn_rails_application'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:132:in `spawn_application'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
/home/madhu/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.02@global/gems/passenger-3.0.9/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99
*/
body:before {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
  content: "SignalException: SIGTERM"; }
```

Comment: Does your exact same code compile on a different machine? If so then you've got a localized issue you might want to contact the Compass team about. Otherwise you can just debug your code by process of elimination if nothing else.